# How do I get these values with Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I’m using the package Cheerio to webscrape from a website (https://www.realmeye.com/items/misc). However, they have made this awkward and I don’t know how to get the values. How would I get the “data alternatives” and then format them so it only says the Server Names.

Here is my code and the website source:

```
request(options, function(err, resp, html) {
    if (!err) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        console.log(html);
        $('span', '#i3180').each(function() {
            var url = $(this).text();

            urls.push(url);
    })
}
```

```html
<td><span class="item" data-item="3180" id="i3180"></span></td>
<td></td>
<td><span class="cheapest-server" data-alternatives="[[&quot;USWest2 Nexus&quot;,100,67,26],[&quot;USWest Nexus&quot;,100,76,25],[&quot;USMidWest2 Nexus&quot;,100,71,25],[&quot;USSouth2 Nexus&quot;,100,50,25],[&quot;USWest3 Nexus&quot;,100,88,24],[&quot;EUSouthWest Nexus&quot;,100,70,24],[&quot;USMidWest Nexus&quot;,100,50,24],[&quot;USEast3 Nexus&quot;,100,92,16],[&quot;EUSouth Nexus&quot;,100,63,12],[&quot;USNorthWest Nexus&quot;,100,60,12],[&quot;EUNorth2 Nexus&quot;,100,88,11],[&quot;EUWest2 Nexus&quot;,100,72,9],[&quot;USSouthWest Nexus&quot;,100,54,9],[&quot;USSouth Nexus&quot;,100,52,9],[&quot;USSouth3 Nexus&quot;,100,93,7],[&quot;USEast2 Nexus&quot;,100,61,3],[&quot;AsiaSouthEast Nexus&quot;,100,99,0],[&quot;USEast Nexus&quot;,100,67,0]]">Australia Nexus</span></td>
```

Comment: Not sure how to do this in Cheerio, but in vanilla JS you’d probably need to look for `const alternatives = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("span#i3180").closest("tr").querySelector("[data-alternatives]").dataset.alternatives)` to get the full `data-alternatives` list (it’s just JSON). Get an array with server names with `alternatives.map(([server]) => server);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cheerio, you get access to an element's attribute with the `attr` method:

`$('selector').attr('attribute')`

The data in `data-alternatives` is a JSON, so all you need to do is to parse it, but before, replace the `&quot;` with `"`

The complete solution would look like this:

```js
let servers = $('.cheapest-server').attr('data-alternatives')
let parsedServers = JSON.parse(servers.replace(/&quot;/g,'"');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thank you. I couldn't seem to find the documentation so the above posts have helped aswell.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for getting data attributes

## Option 1

```
$('.cheapest-server').attr('data-alternatives')
```

## Option 2

```
$('.cheapest-server').data('alternatives')
```

## Documentation:

https://cheerio.js.org doesn't have section links but on the frontpage they have two headlines named

- .attr( name, value )
- .data( name, value )

They refer to the jQuery docs for more examples

- https://api.jquery.com/attr/
- https://api.jquery.com/data/

Side note: In plain JS you'd write

- option 1: `document.querySelector(".cheapest-server").attr("data-alternatives")`
- option 2: `document.querySelector(".cheapest-server").dataset.alternatives`